# ftp file access security

Tags: ssh, security, ftp

I have a client that wants `ftp` access to a certain file in one of our servers

- The server runs `CentOS 7`
- root login is disabled
- password login is disabled (requires ssh key to login)
- ssh is over non-standard port

Is giving the client ftp access to the file feasible / possible? I feel like I have followed all "best practices" to secure the servers, and ftp seems like it may undermine some of this.

Am I missing something here? Will we have to figure out a different approach to maintain security?

Comment: Tell your client that you will not provide FTP, but that there are a plethora of freely-available sftp/scp clients.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is inherently insecure as it transmits everything en clair.

As you already have ssh then either use [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) or [sftp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp) both of which leverage the ssh protocol. You can even use clients like filezilla to connect to your sftp server.

If not already enabled, you can add

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to to so.

You can further lock down the specific user by adding directives to the sshd_config (if that's needed)

```
Match User alice
  # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory /home/alice
  # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

That would only let alice connect using sftp and not ssh/scp.

Answer (score 0):

FTPS (ftp over SSL) exists but consider using SCP if SSH already exists.