# unable to connect ftp on google compute engine instance

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ftp, google-compute-engine

I am using `pure-ftpd` on ubuntu instance.

I can connect to `ftp` from that instance as `ftp localhost` but not from outside

I can access `apache2` server from anywhere by External-IP.

- which firewall / routing rules I need to create more ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/725413/ftp-file-access-security/725447#725447

Answer (score 2):

- Ensure that you have configured pure-ftpd to listen on the relevant interface.
- Ensure that you have ports 20 and 21 open on your external interface.

You may need to configure some ephemeral ports (use the -p switch ) and don't forget to ensure that those ports are open in the relevant firewall too.

Comment: Third point: chances are you shouldn't be using FTP anyways.

Comment: @ceejayoz Good point well made.